# Use Phonegap/Cordova plugin in Windows Store JS/HTML/CSS app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-store

I doing a port of my Phonegap game to Windows Store. I have created a javascript project for the purpose. I have no problems connecting to the basic phonegap distribution (phonegap.js) but when I comes to phonegap plugins I have no idea how to add them to my solution...

For example I need "device.uuid" which is found in the Device-plugin.

Does anyone know how to use a Phonegap plugin when developing a javascript Windows Store app powered by Phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

From the PhoneGap documentation found at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

> Windows Phone 7 and 8 Quirks
>
> The uuid for Windows Phone 7 requires the permission ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE. Microsoft will likely deprecate this property soon. If the capability is not available, the application generates a persistent guid that is maintained for the duration of the application's installation on the device.

Per the documentation, as well as Apple's stance on not using uuid anymore, I would recommend against using it. I know that stinks because it is a nice mechanism for activating/tracking devices and licensing for enterprise apps (what I was using it for). But, there are other good mechanisms for doing this if you search a bit.

Aside from that, your question is really about how to get the DEVICE plugin going. I would again refer back to the above link (just scroll to the top) and note:

> Accessing the Feature
>
> As of version 3.0, Cordova implements device-level APIs as plugins. Use the CLI's plugin command, described in The Command-Line Interface, to add or remove this feature for a project:
>
> ```
> $ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
> ```

That command should be ran from the commandline and while in the directory/folder of your application (that you are building). This causes the config.xml to be updated and the system to download the necessary files to support this functionality on various platforms.

After doing so, the next time you issue a `phonegap build <platform>`, it will merge in the settings and copy the appropriate plugin files.

**EDIT:**
Windows Store (Windows 8) is different than the approach for Windows Phone 7/8. For that platform, see the platform guide about using Visual Studio (express edition will work) [by going here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_win8_index.md.html#Windows%208%20Platform%20Guide).

Comment: Regarding the plugins, what am I supposed to write in <platform> when adding/building to windows 8? 
I have only found examples for the other platforms and I haven't been able to guess the keyword for windows 8...

Comment: So, at the command line you use "wp8" such as: "phonegap build wp8"

Comment: One more note: using the "phonegap" command by itself will show a list of platforms (abbreviated to the "shortcode"/keyword to use)

Comment: When I use the "phonegap" command I see the list of platforms, which confirms my experiments: Windows 8 (not Windows Phone 8) is not supported as a platform via the CLI. 

So I still don't know how to add a plugin to a PhoneGap Windows 8 project...

Comment: Ah, I see. What you need is covered in the Windows 8 platform guide availabe here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_win8_index.md.html#Windows%208%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: I have been reading those instructions before but they don't tell me how to use PhoneGap plugins. 

Somewhere it is mentioned that it is possible to access hardware features via the Windows Store JS API, but that's not what I am looking for.